# First steps on liferay web services

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, liferay

- I followed this [tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/soap-web-services) -documentation about Liferay Web service.
- I runned Lifaray on tomcat
- If I use `http://localhost:8080/api/axis/Portal_UserService?wsdl` by browser I have a response.
- When I create a webService Client on Eclipse and I put this url `http://localhost:8080/api/axis/Portal_UserService?wsdl` in the Service Definition...
  but I have this error message:

  *`No server can be found and WebServiceProject does not exist. Choose an existing project or use the preferences to configure a server runtime.`*
  Why?

[image][image]

Comment: Do you have any progress with this, because I'm having the same problem and haven't found a solution so far?

Answer (score 3):

create dynamic web project and configure a server then add wsdl .

Answer (score 2):

This does not mean that the server (e.g. Liferay) can't be found but notifies you that Eclipse doesn't know where to put/how to configure the resulting WebService: It needs a server runtime and a WebServiceProject - e.g. you can create a WebServiceClient inside a project - if no suitable project exists, eclipse will complain.

So: Everything is fine on the Liferay side. You'll need infrastructure in your IDE to be able to go forward with this operation

Comment: Is possibile to know the steps?

Comment: On that second dialog that you show in the question, click on "server runtime" and select/create a server. Also, do the same for a project that you'll want to use to contain your Webservice client (use the "Client Project" link for that

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any solution to this, for some reason `Eclipse` didn't recognize a valid `wsdl`. I downloaded a trial version of `IntelliJ IDEA 13 Ultimate` and setup the `Web Service Client` through there. Everything worked properly.